# How to get +selected+ from database table using <select> (js)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I try to make the value of a  match with a hide/show javascript script that links to a table that imports data from database. For some reason, it doesn't grab the values for it to execute the code properly, (its not filtering when selected)

I tried to add the value inside the  while the sql is fetching. for te rest i don't know where to continue.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function addRemoveClass(theRows){
        theRows.removeClass("odd even");
        theRows.filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
        theRows.filter(":even").addClass("even");

    }

    var rows = $("table#thetable tr:not(:first-child)");

    addRemoveClass(rows);

$("#selectfield").on("change",function(){

    var selected = this.value;

    if(selected !="12"){
        rows.filter("[REGIOID="+selected+"]").show();
        rows.not("[REGIOID="+selected+"]").hide();
        var visibleRows = rows.filter("[REGIOID="+selected+"]");
        addRemoveClass(visibleRows);
    }else {

        rows.show();
        addRemoveClass(rows);

    }

});
});



</script>
```

```
    <select name="REGIOID" id="selectfield">
        <option value="12">All</option>
        <option value="1">North America</option>
        <option value="2">Latin America</option>
        <option value="3">North Western Europe</option>
        <option value="4">South Europe</option>
        <option value="5">Eastern Europe</option>
        <option value="6">East Asia</option>
        <option value="7">Central Asia</option>
        <option value="8">South Asia</option>
        <option value="9">Southeast Asia and Oceania</option>
        <option value="10">Middle East and North Africa</option>
        <option value="11">Sub-Saharan Africa</option>
    </select>
```

```
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="thetable">
<tr>
<td REGIOID=value">REGIOID</td>
<th>Stelling_iD</th>
<th>Stelling</th>
```

```
echo "<td>".@$stellingen['REGIOID']."</td>";
echo "<td>".@$stellingen['Stelling_ID']."</td>";
echo "<td>".@$stellingen['Stelling']."</td>";
```

I expect the table to filter according to the value of the  element.

Comment: rows is outside of the scope when the onchange event happens.

Comment: @daddygames I don't see what you mean with outside the scope

Comment: because `rows` is defined in `$(document).ready()` and then the event listener for the change event is executed outside of that scope, the `rows` variable is outside of the scope of the change event. Does the variable contain data when your change event occurs?